# Modifier multiplies geometry unnecessarily. "Array" modifier optimization

Tags: optimization

How make that the *Array* modified not produce vertices, but do a procedure similar to *Duplicate Linked* (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>) which saves rather than multiplies geometry unnecessarily?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use the array modifier on a simple index, or on a face, parent the object to be duplicated to the vertex/face object with *Array* modifier, and set *Instancing* options:

[image]

Then you can also <kbd>✲ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>M</kbd> *Make Instance Real* - they will be linked-duplicates of the original object used.